# Caching data in DB or in Files?

Tags: php, database, caching

I am writing an application, where it is necessary to fetch data from a third party website. Unfortunately, a specific type of info needed (a hotel name) can only be obtained by CURLing the webpage, and then parsing it (I'm using XPATHs) looking for an < h1> DOM element.

Since I'm going to run this script many times within the day, and I'll probably have to fetch the same hotel names again and again, I thought that a caching mechanism would be good: Checking if the hotel has been parsed in the past and then decide whether to make the webpage request or not.

However I have two concerns: this implementation is better to be made in a DB (since there will be an ID-Hotel name matching) or in a file? The second one is whether this "optimization" worth the whole trouble. Will I gain some significant speed up?

Comment: yes, use a database (or in memory store, such as redis), yes it will be much faster than making additional http requests, but thats only useful if you actually hit the cache frequantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with DB, because it will give to you more flexibility and functionality for the data manipulation (filtering, sorting, etc.) by default.